# How to remove unwanted text bug in wordpress site

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have installed wordpress 5.4 installed and i create a ecommerce website in woocommerce, I've been having a problem for a long time that in my entire site i see a bug text appear on my top of page. and i see it in view source and see that the text appear on before  tag. i attach the screenshot the bug text. Please let me know how to remove this.

[image: bug text]

[image: view source]

Answer (score 1):

you've probably enter that one in one of your file in your themes
try using notepad++ to locate the 'dis' text

Answer (score 0):

There is almost certainly some extraneous text "dis" that appears outside the PHP tags in a file somewhere. If you have not customised anything, the simplest solution might be to reinstall your theme with the original code.

Otherwise, there is no way to know which file this text is in, by looking at the screenshot. If you say it is on every page, then it's likely in the header.php or footer.php or some other template partial that is loaded on every page. But it could also be in a plugin somewhere. Do you get the same text if you try the default theme (Twenty Twenty)? If so, then the extraneous text is probably in a plugin. You could deactivate all plugins and turn them back on, one by one, to see which one it is.

As Kenneth suggested, you'll need to search through all your files to find it. Notepad++ and VSCode (and I'm sure many other decent text editors) have ways to [search through all files](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk03BkNs2VoG_YH9mDqPuqpUyOlE7jg%3A1597152323671&ei=Q5wyX9HCKMnT1fAPz920uA8&q=notepad%2B%2B%20find%20in%20files&oq=notepad%2B%2B%20find%20in%20files&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECAAQRzoFCAAQkQJQoxhY7B9gtiJoAHABeACAAYgBiAH5BJIBAzcuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiR8J2HoJPrAhXJaRUIHc8uDfcQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) at once. In Notepad++, for example, Ctrl+Shift+F will search for text in all (specified) files in a directory. This would be easier (and simpler) than deactivating your plugins and checking them one-by-one. However, sometimes searching through directories like this can take a long time and it can look like the editor has hung (especially if there are many node_modules folders), so just leave it to search and come back later.